# UIView always top subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

Hi I have a game where I create a subview that handles touch events. But when I add other objects later in the code, they appear in front of that view. So if the user tap the screen on one of these objects the touch won't be registered.
So is there a way to make a UIView always appear on the top?
I have tried this, but it doesn't work:
`view.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with `bringSubviewToFront:`, did the trick for me:

```
[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

Comment: But I create my view in viewdidload and then release it. 
So I can't do that when I add subviews later in the code.

Comment: Keep a pointer to it as a member variable of the class. Or find a way to identify it in your view's `subviews` array (tag or something else).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I just created it as a member variable.

Comment: As far as I know tags are the only way to find a subview without keeping a reference. You can just do: [self.view viewWithTag:tag]; to get the view, then use the code above to bring it to the front.

Answer (score 4):

```
[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you don't want to keep a pointer to the subview as others have suggested you can add subviews using this method:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

with index = 0. This will insert each new subview under the previous. I would personally probably still do what @Alexander is doing in his answer/comments.