# ios 6,7: How to Add a View that will apear over all other views

Tags: xcode, ios7, view, ios6

As my question above, i got a problem to handle this process:

I just wanna add a view which will appear over all other views in application. 
It looks like a youtube when minimize video.
Please help and many thank.

I have try to use:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: That code doesn't do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep a UIView or UIViewController on top of all others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248954/keep-a-uiview-or-uiviewcontroller-on-top-of-all-others), [UIView always top subview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628586/uiview-always-top-subview)

Comment: Thank for your help but its still does not helpful.
My idea is display a UIView/UIViewController on Top-level that mean this view will display front of all other view whenever we switch between them.
Of course this view will has own gesture reg to know when and how we can disable it

Comment: by the way, i try and found a solution is that:
will use AppDelegate and call to .window to addSubview
Thanks for your help!